# href tag within Placemark in KML not displaying

Tags: google-maps, kml, cdata

Im creating a map with many `Placemarks` where the description is programatically generated. The HTML formatting works, I'm using the `CDATA` attribute but for some reason the `href` tags dont work?

[image]

Ideally its shows as a normal hyperlink instead. like eg,

[Facebook](https://facebook.com)
[Twitter](https://www.twitter.com)

This is the code inside the KML file

`<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?">Facebook</a><br>`

Whats going on..? Is there a way to fix this?

Example:

```
<Placemark>
<name>Dhaba 1376 North Indian cuisine</name>
<description><![CDATA[Address:<br>#04-64 Blk144 Upper Bukit Timah Rd, Beauty World Hawker Centre 588177<br><br>Opening Hours:<br>Open everyday except Monday afternoon, 11am to 10pm<br><br>Shop Recommendations:<br>Mixed Kebab Platter<br><br>Other Details:<br><br><br>Contributor:<br>OldieGoodieHawker<br><br>Share your support for this stall!:<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fhawker.help&quote=I+just+dapaoed+from+Dhaba+1376+North+Indian+cuisine+%40+%2304-64+Blk144+Upper+Bukit+Timah+Rd%2C+Beauty+World+Hawker+Centre%21+Dabao+and+help+the+digitally+disadvantaged+hawkers+near+you+today%21+Find+them+at+https%3A%2F%2Fhawker.help">Facebook</a><br><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=I+just+dapaoed+from+Dhaba+1376+North+Indian+cuisine+%40+%2304-64+Blk144+Upper+Bukit+Timah+Rd%2C+Beauty+World+Hawker+Centre%21+Dabao+and+help+the+digitally+disadvantaged+hawkers+near+you+today%21+Find+them+at+https%3A%2F%2Fhawker.help">Twitter</a><br><br><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fhawker.help&quote=I+just+dapaoed+from+Dhaba+1376+North+Indian+cuisine+%40+%2304-64+Blk144+Upper+Bukit+Timah+Rd%2C+Beauty+World+Hawker+Centre%21+Dabao+and+help+the+digitally+disadvantaged+hawkers+near+you+today%21+Find+them+at+https%3A%2F%2Fhawker.help.%0ABackstory%3A%0Anan">Facebook (With backstory)</a><br><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=I+just+dapaoed+from+Dhaba+1376+North+Indian+cuisine+%40+%2304-64+Blk144+Upper+Bukit+Timah+Rd%2C+Beauty+World+Hawker+Centre%21+Dabao+and+help+the+digitally+disadvantaged+hawkers+near+you+today%21+Find+them+at+https%3A%2F%2Fhawker.help.%0ABackstory%3A%0Anan">Twitter (With backstory)</a><br>]]></description>
<styleUrl>#icon-1577-E65100</styleUrl>
<Point><coordinates>103.7761346,1.3424354,0</coordinates></Point>
</Placemark>
```

Comment: What about providing a [mcve]?

Comment: @MrUpsidown i thought the specific line would be enough since its just an example, but ive added the placemark

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your `<Placemark>` (missing closing quote on the URL)

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php>Facebook</a>
```

should be:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php">Facebook</a>
```

This:

```
<Placemark>
<name>sample point</name>
<description><![CDATA[Address:<br>
this is the address<br><br>
Opening Hours:<br>
Mon-Sat, 5.30am-1.30pm<br><br>
Other Details:<br>
blabbiltiy blabbity bla<br>
Share your support for this stall!:
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php>Facebook</a>]]></description>
<styleUrl>#icon-1577-E65100</styleUrl>
<Point><coordinates>103.8578165,1.306714,0</coordinates></Point>
</Placemark>
```

Should be:

```
<Placemark>
<name>sample point</name>
<description><![CDATA[Address:<br>this is the address<br><br>
Opening Hours:<br>
Mon-Sat, 5.30am-1.30pm<br><br>
Other Details:<br>
blabbiltiy blabbity bla<br>
Share your support for this stall!:
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php">Facebook</a>]]></description>
<styleUrl>#icon-1577-E65100</styleUrl>
<Point><coordinates>103.8578165,1.306714,0</coordinates></Point>
</Placemark>
```

[proof of concept](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20210611_PlacemarkB.kml)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response! sorry thats my fault in copy pasting over, here's an actual example, ill edit my post

Comment: Also, i just tested it on google maps, it does not seem to work even though your proof of concept link works..?  https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=1tbjd3Px5RNIROzhr-yEwramry7Mn1qa_&ll=1.3067140000000041%2C103.85781600000001&z=17

Comment: please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (**in your question itself**).

Comment: BTW - your [link](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=1tbjd3Px5RNIROzhr-yEwramry7Mn1qa_&ll=1.3067140000000041%2C103.85781600000001&z=17) in your comment requires access, so is not helpful.  Please see [ask]

Comment: thats so weird, can you see it now? its public

Comment: Even if it is public (now, it wasn't when I first looked), links with information required to answer a question are frowned upon (see [ask]), all the information required to answer the question should be in the question itself.

Comment: All the URLs in the KML from your ["MyMap"](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=1tbjd3Px5RNIROzhr-yEwramry7Mn1qa_&ll=1.3067140000000168%2C103.85781600000001&z=17) work for me, except the one for the "sample point", which is incorrect (it doesn't match the KML you posted in your question or the KML in my answer).  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/vpajLnb2/1/)

Comment: the urls are not the problem, the problem is the href shortening isnt working

Comment: I don't see anything in your question about URL shortening.  Can you provide more details on what is happening and what is supposed to happen in your question?

Comment: Its in the question. I want to see a hyperlink, it shows the full URL without the text instead.